# Cannot access data passed in redirect

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-4

so i am using laravel 4.2. my problem is I cannot echo the data from my redirect route. how can i access it the right way? I tried searching to get the right answer but it didn't help me.

```
public function postLogin()
        {   
                $timeIn = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
                $userLog = New UserLog;
                $userLog->username = Input::get('username');
                $userLog->time_in = $timeIn;
                $userLog->save();
                $users = $userLog;

                 return Redirect::route( 'account' )
                           ->with( 'users', $users );

        }

public function account(){
    $data = Session::get('users');
    var_dump($data );
    echo $data->username;// this one throws an error
    }
```

I can see that it has values in var_dump($data).

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[92]
public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'UserLog' (length=7)
public 'timestamps' => boolean false
public 'table' => string 'userlogs' (length=8)
protected 'connection' => null
protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
protected 'perPage' => int 15
public 'incrementing' => boolean true
protected 'attributes' => 
array (size=3)
  'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'time_in' => string '2015-07-28 15:11:43' (length=19)
  'id' => int 240
protected 'original' => 
array (size=3)
  'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'time_in' => string '2015-07-28 15:11:43' (length=19)
  'id' => int 240
```

these are my routes file

```
Route::get('/login', array(
    'uses' => 'TimeController@login', 
    'as' => 'login')                
    );

Route::post('/postLogin', array(
        'uses' => 'SessionsController@postLogin',
        'as' => 'postLogin')            
        );

Route::get('/account', array(
        'uses' => 'SessionsController@account',
        'as' => 'account')          
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt like i made a huge success just by displaying the data, and the problem causing me to get errors is the __PHP_Incomplete_Class as you can see on my var_dump($data) above. To access the $data correctly, i need to unserialize it first before accessing the regular way. here i just added one line of code and everything works very well. thanks to this post [unserializing](https://github.com/codenitive/laravel-oneauth/issues/14).

```
public function account(){
$data = Session::get('users');
$data = unserialize(serialize($data)); //added code to unserialize the __PHP_Incomplete_Class
var_dump($data);
echo $data->username;
}
```

in my var_dump($data) the __PHP_Incomplete_Class is now gone

```
  object(UserLog)[143]
  public 'timestamps' => boolean false
  protected 'table' => string 'userlogs' (length=8)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
      'time_in' => string '2015-07-28 19:57:08' (length=19)
      'id' => int 276
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=3)
      'username' => string 'user' (length=4)
      'time_in' => string '2015-07-28 19:57:08' (length=19)
      'id' => int 276
```